# How can I calculate an average value within 6-month periods?

Tags: r, dataframe, average

I have a CSV file in which there are multiple numerical fields. Trying to calculate averages for a variable for every 6 months across a 5 year period and output into a data frame. Note there are also **invalid entries** (such as "..") in some of the numerical fields which need to be omitted when calculating the averages, as otherwise they throw off an error.

```
     #installing and loading packages
install.packages("dplyr")
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

#importing data file
X1010014501_eng <- read_csv("1010014501-eng.csv")
View(X1010014501_eng)

mydata<-read_csv("1010014501-eng.csv")
print(mydata)

#seeing number of rows and columns
dim(mydata)

#duplicate data
mydata1 <- mydata


#calculating mean for bank rate in each 6 month period for the 5 years
mean(mydata1$`Bank rate`)
```

The code is not complete, I am unable to figure out how to establish a mean calculation for every 6 months over 5 years. Here is a snippet of the data

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a sample for the data via `dput` it will be easier to work with.

Comment: Please provide data in a copy-pasteable format using `dput()`, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17303805). Also, include some of the "invalid" values in your example data assuming that’s part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your periods to start January 1, you can use `lubridate::semester()` to create 6-month groupings:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

dat %>%
  group_by(date = str_replace_all(
    semester(date, with_year = TRUE),
    c("\\.1" = " Jan-Jun", "\\.2" = " Jul-Dec")
  )) %>%
  summarize(rate = mean(rate))
```

```
   date          rate
   <chr>        <dbl>
 1 2015 Jan-Jun  3.87
 2 2015 Jul-Dec  5.79
 3 2016 Jan-Jun  5.21
 4 2016 Jul-Dec  5.85
 5 2017 Jan-Jun  6.1 
 6 2017 Jul-Dec  4.92
 7 2018 Jan-Jun  4   
 8 2018 Jul-Dec  5.82
 9 2019 Jan-Jun  5.29
10 2019 Jul-Dec  3.35
```

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

dat <- tibble(
  date = ymd("2014-12-31") + days(sample(365*5, 200, replace = TRUE)),
  rate = sample(0:10, 200, replace = TRUE)
)
```